# Swift NSDate get current date but strip Year, Month, and Day

Tags: swift, nsdate

I am trying to get the current date using swift. I have that taken care of but it gets the year month and day and I really only want the current hour and minute. The reason being is that I am trying to later on compare a created date that only has an hour and minute. I am currently just using this

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: Date())
let hour = components.hour
let minute = components.minute
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me with one more thing. I am trying to apply the same logic to the next similar issue i'm having. I have                 let time1 = NSDateComponents()
        time1.hour = 8
        time1.minute = 54
        
        let date1: NSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(time1)!                                     and I can't seem to get it to work without errors

Comment: You should post a new question. Include your code and the errors.

Comment: @rob mayoff Do this work for swift3?  I write `[ .year, .month ]` . It shows `Calendar.Component` cannot be used with array literal.

Comment: I have updated my answer to Swift 3. Note that the method name is now `dateComponents(_:from:)`. (Formerly it was `components(_:fromDate:)`).